# multiple dispatcher is requiered

Tags: servlets

did we need multiple request-dispatcher to send multiple value to the same page 
I have written this.

```
        String name=rs.getString("itemname");
        String code=rs.getString("itemcode");
        String lpr=rs.getString("lastpurchase");
        String ur=rs.getString("unitrate");
        String pq=rs.getString("pquantity");
        String cpq=rs.getString("costpquan");
        ServletContext context= getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd=context.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp")
        rd.forward(request,response);
```

I need to send all these variables to a same page.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need multiple dispatchers. You simply need to store each value in a separate request attribute. A better option would be to create an object (`Item`, for example) containing all these values, and to store this object in a single request attribute.

```
Item item = new Item(name, code, lpr, ur, pq, cpq);
request.setAttribute("item", item);
rd.forward(request,response);
```

You should also use much better names for your variables.